# Is there something like Grapher.app for Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, software-rec, charts, calculator

On a Mac, there is a Grapher.app which has many functions like: ordinary graphing, polar graphing, lin-log and log-log graphing, 3d graphing, derivatives, integrals, implicitly defined functions, equation solvers and much much more.

Is there anything similar (and preferably cheap/free) on Windows? I've seen many ordinary "graphing calculator" apps that can't do much more than graphing an ordinary function like `y=3x^2`.

I especially need the implicitly defined function grapher so I can graph `4y^2-5*e^(-2x)-x*y=4`?

I've tried Wolfram Alpha, but I need to see more than the limited window it gives me.

Comment: You can use GeoGebra 3D as of 2023.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little searching I found the free [Microsoft Mathematics](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15702) which does a lot of the stuff I was looking for.

> With the Mathematics 4.0 free download, you get a full-featured graphing calculator with a formulas and equations library, a triangle solver, a unit conversion tool, ink handwriting support, and more.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone stumbles across this question, like I did:

Try **Graph** by **Ivan Johansen**. You can find the newest version (as well as the source code) at [www.padowan.dk](http://www.padowan.dk).

Answer (score 1):

Winplot is the best free graphing software for Windows that I'm aware of: [Winplot](http://math.exeter.edu/rparris/winplot.html).  Indeed, I came to this question because I'm looking for something for a Mac that will do as much as Winplot does (Grapher has some things it does better, but other things Winplot does and Grapher doesn't do).

Answer (score 0):

There's the [Graphing Calculator](http://www.pacifict.com/Home.html) that came with Macs before Grapher was introduced (in 10.3). It's sorta expensive (at $100) but really easy to use and powerful.

Comment: that is pretty expensive. After a little searching I found the free [Microsoft Mathematics](http://www.microsoft.com/education/products/student/math/default.aspx) which does a lot of the stuff I was looking for. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Albert You should put that (the Microsoft Mathematics) as an answer, and maybe accept it (though I appreciate the points), as not everybody reads the comments.

Comment: @Albert I second that, please use this system, it helps people find the answer more quickly. @CajunLuke I'd still give you +1 if you mind the points :)

Comment: and @slhck, I didn't know I could answer my own questions. Thanks for letting me know.